# Reading Card Holder's Name by Card IO Library

Tags: ios, card.io

i know this is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213558/getting-card-holder-name) which has been previously closed.

But i have downloaded the Card IO SDK & in respective static library , i did not find any way of getting the Card Holder's name (E.g 7 -> Mr A B Person) ? Can any one able to solve this problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Josh from card.io here. No, card.io does not currently scan the cardholder's name.

Comment: what about Expiry Date?

Comment: @Rookie we're working on bringing it back. No ETA now, though; don't expect it particularly soon.