# Detect card holder's name

Tags: card.io

First of all, Thanks for this great sdk and easy integration process.

While using this, I came across some custom needs that need to be incorporated in my app. That is, detecting card holder's name. Is there a way we can do that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844028/reading-card-holders-name-by-card-io-library/

Answer (score 0):

Raghav, at present card.io is not able to detect the cardholder name. We do hope to add that feature sometime in the future, though.

Comment: that would be one mighty feature, can't wait to see it

Answer (score 0):

Why not get the time of sale, customer name and cc number and use intent on the next activity. It takes 3-5 seconds to enter a name, maybe less.

```
   TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
   textView.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(getBaseContext(),
   System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME |
   DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_12HOUR));  
   custname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.custname);

   //IN THE CARD.io SECTION RIGHT HERE
   if (scanResult.isExpiryValid()) {
   final TextView xxx =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
   String threex = xxx.getText().toString();
   final TextView x =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custname);   
   String onex = x.getText().toString();

   Intent intent= new Intent(MyScanActivity.this,YourNextActivity.class)
   .putExtra("date",threex)
   .putExtra("inputPrice",twox)
   .putExtra("Card Number",resultStr)
   .putExtra("customername",onex)
   startActivity(intent);
   finish();
```

Comment: The reason for using card io is that it would scan the details by itself, so that we dont have to put the details manually.